# Amazon S3 Bucket GET request count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get, get-request

If I execute an Athena Query such as select obj.name from  where obj.date > '2021-01-01',
**How much Amazon S3 Get request would be considered in AWS bill?**

1. Single Get request
2. Number of file which will fulfill the filter criteria i.e. if 150 file are having obj.date field with greater parameter value, 150 get request would be considered?

Actually i have received AWS bill in which my GET request count is in billions!!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Athena will only be able to compare the value, once it has read the value. So that means it will presumably do a GET request for every file that is in your bucket. It won't know beforehand what files are fitting your criteria, so if there are only 150 files that match your criteria, but 1000 files in the bucket, it will read all 1000 files.